# css : strange behaviour when displaying divs side by side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display some divs side by side using the css property `display:inline-block;` for the children and `position:relative` for the parent/container as described in the code below :

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px; position: relative;">
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 130px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display:inline-block;">
         test test test
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 130px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display:inline-block;">
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 130px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display:inline-block;">
         test test test
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 130px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display:inline-block;">
         test test test
    </div>
</div>
```

But the result was different when one of the those divs contain a long text

[image]

What's the explanation of this.

Comment: do not use inline css. use a separate style sheet! we are no more in the '90s!

Comment: I would never use `inline-block` to display container in a row.
Take a look at `flex-box`. You HAVE to learn that. You can layout whole websites with flex boxes. w3schools has some good tutorials.

Comment: @Lelio Faieta it's just for testing :)

Comment: one of the main reasons not to use inline css is for code readibility. And when you ask someone to help you you should take it into account

Comment: @Aaron3219 I think his question was about the unexpected result, why one of the divs didn't stood on the same level of the others.

Comment: Reason is that the default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline` … change it to something else, if you don’t like its effect.

Comment: @Aaron3219 thanks it's work fine now but what is the reason for this result

Comment: Because of what misorude said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `inline-block` will align everything as its center / base-line.

Either use: display: flex for parent div and `block` for child div or use `display: table-cell` for child div.

```html
<div style="margin-top: 20px; position: relative; display: flex">
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 80px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display: block;">
         test test test
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 80px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display: block;">
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test 
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 80px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display: block">
         test test test
    </div>
    <div style="margin: 15px; border: solid 2px; width: 80px; height: 130px; padding: 10px; text-align: center; display: block;">
         test test test
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or specify `vertical-align: middle` (or another value, depending on what one wants) on each of the `body > div > div` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Either give the sorrounding div

```
display: flex;
```

Or give each of the child divs

```
vertical-align: text-top; // Or another alignment
```

The flex box approach is in my opinion the better. Flex box in general can be used for a lot. Especially dynamic content. But even for static content it is a great way to make sure to fill exactly what you want to fill.
Heres a guide to help anyone interested in flex boxes (worth the read):
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

The vertical-align approach is great aswell. The reason this is needed, as mentioned in other answers and comments is because by default inline-block will align everything as its center / base-line.

Comment: I think your answer would be more useful if it provided an explanation of what is causing the problem, which you indeed touched upon but only after attempting to give a solution (which is just one of many).

Comment: @amn Thank you for the feedback :)

Answer (score -3):

add one more style `float: left;` to all divs. Will solve the problem.

Comment: `float: left` also work but remember to add another div with `clear: both` at the end.

Comment: Why do you want to clear @DanielTran `float: left` also works fine at the end

Comment: If you have another div following then everything will be messed up